# How to get Auto complete Youtube Search using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I read many questions on Stackoverflow related to this question but there is no thing really solve the problem

I have Array `selected_keywords_arr`
I wan to make a loop on each value on this array to get auto complete Youtube search ***after Clicking a button*** I implemented the same function but in PHP
using this

```
 foreach ($youtube_sugeestion_arr as $val ) {
      
        $url = sprintf("http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?hl=en&ds=yt&client=youtube&hjson=t&cp=1&q=%s&alt=json", urlencode($val));
// rest of the code
```

I just need to do the same using Javascript or Ajax

Comment: Can you please check this answer, I know this is not search using loop but the concept is same.. You can implement the JS code inside on loop - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15829767/generate-a-url-for-youtube-search

Comment: Thanks, it works but it downloads the result in txt file and I need the result as a an Array or json or string

Comment: Also to check I though the loop gonna work actual,
` for (var i = 0; i < selected_keywords_arr.length; i++) {var url="http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&ds=yt&q="+selected_keywords_arr[i] ;var win=window.open(url, '_blank');console.log(win)}`